# how to join values from first elements of list to next position? - python

Tags: python

I need to in some type of way pass the first elements of a list to the next one, but i couldn't figure out a way to do it.

What i have is this list:

```
list_lists = [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

And the output would be:

```
list_output = [[1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly what `itertools.accumulate` is doing:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(list_lists))
[[1], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

Comment: Nice use of *accumulate* here to List of lists..

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```py
lists = [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6]]

for i in range(1, len(lists)):
    lists[i] = lists[i-1] + lists[i]

print(lists)
```

The output you get is:

`[[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

Starting from the second sub-list (index 1), add the previous sub-list to current sub-list's starting. In python this can be done easily using just the `+` operator. Just repeat this for all the sub-lists after, and you're good to go!